# Find canonical images in set with python/opencv pandas

Tags: python, image, pandas, opencv, canonical-link

I have a large dataset of images captured from a video stream and I'd like to extract a canonical dataset from them. For example, the dataset may be comprised of 60% just background, 20% background with a human in it, 20% very dark images.

As a naive prototype, I thought to compute the average RGB of every image and bin similar RGB values together and take a random sample from each bin.

```
rgb_avg = {}
for i in img_list:
    img = cv2.imread(i)
    rgb_avg[i] = np.mean(img)
rgb_series = pd.Series(rgb_avg)
bins = pd.cut(rgb_series,bins=10)
```

This leaves me with a series of categories and can't really find a good tutorial on how to work with this series and randomly sample from each bin. How do I split my RGB series into 10 bins and randomly sample a file from each bin?

Comment: Your code looks short and clear.  If it works, I think you've answered your own question.

Comment: Great thanks, moved my edit to the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish it via:

```
rgb_avg = {}
for i in img_list:
    img = cv2.imread(i)
    rgb_avg[i] = np.mean(img)
rgb_series = pd.Series(rgb_avg)
bins = pd.cut(rgb_series,bins=10)
bin_values = sorted([b.right for b in bins.unique()])
img_bins = {b : [] for b in bin_values}
for img,rgb in rgb_avg.items():
    for b in bin_values:
        if rgb <= b:
            img_bins[b].append(img)
for b in img_bins:
    img = np.random.choice(img_bins[b])
    plt.imshow(cv2.imread(img))
    plt.show()
```

May not be the most efficient but it gets the job done.